# Placing bibtex entries inline

Tags: biblatex, bibtex

I would like to place the name and the title of a BibTeX entry inline.

Something like:

> [JD2012] John Doe, Title of Paper.

Any Idea?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Answer (score 3):

`Biblatex` has two macros called `\citeauthor` and `\citetitle` which one can use. You can either just write them one after the other or define yourself a new command like the `mycite` in my code example below:

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{test,
    author={A. Uthor},
    title = {A neat paper},
    journal = {Some random Journal},
    year = {2013}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=alphabetic]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\newcommand{\mycite}[1]{\cite{#1} \citeauthor{#1} \citetitle{#1}}

\begin{document}
\cite{test} \citeauthor{test} \citetitle{test}

\mycite{test}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

The only missing point is the first name of the Author but maybe you can live with that.

Comment: @user25179 Sorry I don't really understand your comment. My answer makes explicitly use of this ``citeauthor`` command.

Answer (score 1):

in [the tex faq](http://texfaq.org/FAQ-bibinline), the `bibentry` and `inlinebib` packages are suggested; there may be restrictions on what `.bst` you can use.  `biblatex` can do this as well, i think (an expert may be able to suggest how ... i'm not one of those).